# Querying nested associative array from database issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hi I'm trying to query an associative array where the end result should look like this json array below. However I want the data section and the id name section to query once for every node and the adjacencies section to query multiple times if a node has multiple adjacencies, how do I query one section of this nested array more than one time if the condition is met and the rest once all while maintaining this struture but with multiple or none adjacencies for a node?

```
   var json =[{
        "adjacencies": [{
           "nodeTo": "graphnode9",
           "nodeFrom": "graphnode5",
           "data": {}
        }],
        "data": {
            "$color": "#C74243",
            "$type": "triangle",
        },
        "id": "graphnode5",
        "name": "graphnode5"
  }];
```

Here is my Database structure

```
nodes                 Relationships                      
-----                 -------------
id int(11),           id int(11),
name varchar(35),     to int(11), //this is the destination node from the id relation 
color varchar(7),     data varchar(0) null
type varchar (12),    Foreign key (id) references nodes(id)
Primary key (id)       

engine = innodb
```

Here is my attempt at getting an associative array but it queries all at once and duplicates the whole strucute.

```
function getjson(){  
    $db = adodbConnect();
    $query = "SELECT nodes.*, relationships.* FROM nodes inner JOIN relationships ON nodes.id = relationships.id";
    $result = $db -> Execute($query);

    while($row=$result->FetchRow()) {
        $id = (float)$row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $color1 = $row['color'];
        $type1 = $row['type'];
        $to = (float)$row['to'];

        $array = array(
            "adjacencies:" => array(
                "nodeTo" => "$to",
                "nodeFrom" => "$id",
                "data" => array()
            ),
            "data" => array(
               "$"."color" => $color1,
               "$"."type" => $type1
            ),
            "id".":" => $id,
            "name".":" => $name
        );

    }
    print"$array";
    json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: What does your result array look like? You are only getting one result because you keep rewriting the array. You probably mean  `$array = array(` to `$array[] = array(`

Comment: @jcubic lol I almost posted that edit.

Comment: my result array is this : Array ( [adjacencies:] => Array ( [nodeTo] => 2 [nodeFrom] => 1 [data] => Array ( ) ) [data] => Array ( [$color] => #83548B [$type] => circle ) [id:] => 1 [name:] => Blue Jay ), which is fine but I want to query the array inside adjacencies more than once if the condition is met but still maintain the overall structure except with more adjacencies

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your array outside of the loop and add items to it

```
$array = array();
while($row=$result->FetchRow()) {
    $array[] = array(
        "adjacencies:" => array(
            "nodeTo" => (float)$row['to'],
            "nodeFrom" => (float)$row['id'],
            "data" => array()
        ),
        "data" => array(
           '$color' => $row['color'],
           '$type' => $row['type']
        ),
        "id" => (float)$row['id'],
        "name" => $row['name']
    );

}
```

Comment: how would I add items to it? if its nested array then should I test that one specifically?

Comment: @user1902588 this `$array[] = ` add element to the array, if this what you're asking.